# How to change four corners of FLVPlayback using action script?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I want to change four corners(Corner Pin) of FLVPlayback using action script like bellow image.

[image]

Are there any methods to achieve this task from action script ?

Comment: Do you want to pass directly from the first image to the last, or to make the b transformation between?

Comment: I want to move(up,down,left,right) one corner of flvplayback using action script like B image.

Comment: Is there any way to do this to Flvplayback? http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/p10triangles/method.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DistortImage Class`.

The original Actionscript 2.0 version of the class was written by Thomas Pfeiffer (aka kiroukou), inspired by Andre Michelle (andre-michelle.com). Ruben Swieringa rewrote Thomas Pfeiffer's class in Actionscript 3.0, making some minor changes/additions.

Here is a demo [from Ruben Swieringa](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage).

This Class works with a `Bitmap image`. It has to be adapted to a `flvplayback component` by using draw method every enterFrame.

**Modus operandi**

You first get [the AS3 Class here](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/DistortImage/source/source/org/flashsandy/display/DistortImage.as.html).

You place this code into an `.as file` and name it `DistortImage`. You place this file into this hierarchy of folders: org > flashsandy > diqplay > `DistortImage.as`

You have a MovieClip linked `DragBtn` in your library. You put the following code in the actionScript panel of your .fla:

```
import org.flashsandy.display.*;

vidPlayer.source = 'http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/caption_video.flv';
vidPlayer.scaleMode = 'exactFit';
vidPlayer.skin = null;
vidPlayer.visible = false; // we only see the Bitmap drawn

var C:Sprite= new Sprite(); // Sprite container
C.x = C.y = 100; // video position
this.addChild(C);

var shape:Shape = new Shape();
this.C.addChild(shape);

var iw:int = vidPlayer.width;
var ih:int = vidPlayer.height;

var distortion:DistortImage = new DistortImage(iw, ih, 2, 2);
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(iw, ih);
var center:Point;

function getDisplayObjectCenter(child:DisplayObject, x:Number = 0, y:Number = 0):Point {
    center = new Point();
    center.x = child.x + child.width / 2 + x;
    center.y = child.y + child.height / 2 + y;
    return center;
}

function Enter(e:Event):void {
    this.shape.graphics.clear();
    this.bitmapData.draw(vidPlayer); // video drawn enterFrame
    distortion.setTransform(this.shape.graphics,
                            this.bitmapData, 
                            this.getDisplayObjectCenter(this.d1, 0, 0), 
                            this.getDisplayObjectCenter(this.d2, 0, 0), 
                            this.getDisplayObjectCenter(this.d3, 0, 0), 
                            this.getDisplayObjectCenter(this.d4, 0, 0));
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Enter);

var d1:DragBtn = new DragBtn();
d1.x = d1.y = 0;
this.C.addChild(d1);

var d2:DragBtn = new DragBtn();
d2.x = iw;
d2.y = 0;
this.C.addChild(d2);

var d3:DragBtn = new DragBtn();
d3.x = iw;
d3.y = ih - 60;
this.C.addChild(d3);

var d4:DragBtn = new DragBtn();
d4.x = 0;
d4.y = ih - 60;
this.C.addChild(d4);

d1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
d2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
d3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
d4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
function drag(e:MouseEvent):void {e.target.startDrag();}

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, up);
function up(e:MouseEvent):void {stopDrag();}
```

**Result**

Then you can deform your video like that:

[image]

The flashandmath method probably also works adapted to a video.

Comment: Thank you helloflash...when I try to drag from the corners following error happen.`TypeError: Error #1006: startDrag is not a function.
 at Distort_fla::MainTimeline/drag()`

Comment: @pudubu - That's because your drag button is an instance of the `Button Class`. You just have to click on DragButton in your Library > Properties > Type > `MovieClip`. Or to create a MovieClip named DragButton.